# Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel Test confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, relative-risk, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I'm looking at a collection of very similar dichotomous outcome studies, and in order to assess the relative risk of an intervention and account for study variability, I believe I should use the Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel relative risk to produce a weighed estimate, of the form

$R_{CMH} = \frac{\Sigma \frac{a_{i}(c_{i} + d_{i})}{n_{i}}) }{\Sigma \frac{c_{i}(a_{i} + b_{i})}{n_{i}}) }$

as detailed [here](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704-ep713_confounding-em/BS704-EP713_Confounding-EM7.html). This is easily implemented in R directly, but I have had difficulties in determining how the 95% confidence intervals are calculated, and I could not find it in the R documentation or elsewhere. It would be useful to have this information, as I also want to interrogate my results using a different method and want to check for consistency. Does anyone know how it is typically calculated?

Comment: There is a formula in the R documentation, but it's really strangely written and when I put numbers into it, values seem unrealistic: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mStats/versions/3.2.2/topics/mhrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is indeed a bit strange, this seems to be the 'canonical' variance estimator of [Greenland & Robins (1985)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2530643).

Not to confuse you more with my own notation, we're working towards the risk ratio of group $1$ over group $2$, each of which were measured in $k$ strata of sample size $n$ and with number of 'successes' $x$. The double subscript $n_{k1}$ refers to the $k$th stratum in group $1$, and the subscript $_+$ is 'sum across' (groups $1$ and $2$).

The point estimate for the risk ratio in this notation is:

$$\mathrm{RR_{MH}}=({\sum}_kx_{k1}n_{k2}/n_{k+})/({\sum}_kx_{k2}n_{k1}/n_{k+})
$$

The variance of the *log* of this estimate is:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(log(\mathrm{RR_{MH}}))=\hat\sigma^2=\frac{{\sum}_k(n_{k1}n_{k2}(x_{k+})-x_{k1}x_{k2}n_{k+})/n^2_{k+}}{({\sum}_kx_{k1}n_{k2}/n_{k+})/({\sum}_kx_{k2}n_{k1}/n_{k+})}
$$

These are combined into a confidence interval with $z$ your applicable standard normal quantile (e.g. $\Phi^{-1}(0.975)\sim 1.96$ for two-sided $\alpha=0.05$):

$$
\big(\mathrm{RR_{MH}}\times exp(-z\hat\sigma),\ \mathrm{RR_{MH}}\times exp(z\hat\sigma)\big)
$$

I said 'canonical' above because this was (I believe?) among the first to be published & will be the one you get by default in most software, though I prefer [Miettinen-Nurminen (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.4780040211) or [Sato (1990)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2531631) in that order myself. As a shameless self-plug I wrote up a formula cheat sheet for most of these methods (for a SAS macro primarily for risk differences) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q3ya7v186zalr8s7u4bwx/riskdiff.pdf?rlkey=4xwah863nfk1no9cwlq6jyeek).